# Efficient way to disable a user to sudo via puppet

Tags: puppet, manifest, sudo, visudo

I have puppet 6 installed in my environment and would like to ensure that the user `centos` cannot `sudo` on all of my agents. I can create somethings like this:

```
modules/sudoer/manifests/disable_sudo.pp

# Manage the sudoers file
class sudoers {
  file { '/etc/sudoers':
    source => 'puppet:///modules/sudoers/sudoers',
    mode => '0440', 
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
  }
}
```

And then create a `modules/sudoers/files/sudoers` file and put the content I like in there and make sure the centos line is commented out:

```
#centos ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But this is very lengthy and in puppet 3, I could only use `sudo::disable_centos: true` in the `hiera`. Is there a better way for letting puppet prevent the user `centos` from sudo? Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with Puppet 3 versus Puppet 6 and sounds more like you had a different sudo module before. Did you change the sudo module when you upgraded to Puppet 6?

Comment: Based on your "puppet 3" comment, do you still have `modules/sudo/` installed, it may be in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/<your-environment>/modules` or `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules` ?

Comment: Used to have puppet sudo module v 3.0.1 and had to comment out the centos line.  Right now I'm using puppet sudo module v 2.4.3 which is old and needs to be upgraded.

Comment: So, upgrade the module (please also provide the link from forge, usually the line is in `Puppetfile`, or if you installed manually ... is the output of `puppet module list --tree`, so you can see also the dependencies), and let us know how it goes.

Comment: There are at least 16 different sudo modules presently available from the Forge, but no puppet/sudo or puppetlabs/sudo.  The version numbers rule out many of these -- the latest version for most of them is less than 2.0 -- but the remaining ones have latest version numbers exceeding 5.  In other words, we've no idea what sudo module or modules you are using. And it matters.

Comment: @azbarcea, this is the one I need to install: https://github.com/saz/puppet-sudo The output of the puppet module list --tree has this listed for sudo: ── saz-sudo (v2.4.3)

Comment: Here is the link from forge: https://forge.puppet.com/saz/sudo

I would like to have a small class, if 'centos_sudo_allowed = false' (default) then it ensure these two lines are in '/etc/sudoers:'

'root ALL=(ALL) ALL
#centos ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'

And if it's not allowed, the sudoer file will have the following two lines in it:

'root ALL=(ALL) ALL
centos ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'


Thank you